# How use pytest to unit test sqlalchemy orm classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, pytest

I want to write some py.test code to test 2 simple sqlalchemy ORM classes that were created based on [this Tutorial](http://zetcode.com/db/sqlalchemy/orm/). The problem is, how do I set a the database in py.test to a test database and rollback all changes when the tests are done? Is it possible to mock the database and run tests without actually connect to de database?

here is the code for my classes:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship

eng = create_engine('mssql+pymssql://user:pass@host/my_database')

Base = declarative_base(eng)
Session = sessionmaker(eng)
intern_session = Session()

class Author(Base):
    __tablename__ = "Authors"

    AuthorId = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    Name = Column(String)  
    Books = relationship("Book")

    def add_book(self, title):
        b = Book(Title=title, AuthorId=self.AuthorId)
        intern_session.add(b)
        intern_session.commit()

class Book(Base):
    __tablename__ = "Books"

    BookId = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    Title = Column(String)      
    AuthorId = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("Authors.AuthorId"))    

    Author = relationship("Author")
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I usually do that this way:

1. I do not instantiate engine and session with the model declarations, instead I only declare a Base with no bind:

   ```py
   Base = declarative_base()
   ```

   and I only create a session when needed with

   ```py
   engine = create_engine('<the db url>')
   db_session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
   ```

   You can do the same by not using the `intern_session` in your `add_book` method but rather use a `session` parameter.

   ```py
   def add_book(self, session, title):
       b = Book(Title=title, AuthorId=self.AuthorId)
       session.add(b)
       session.commit()
   ```

   It makes your code more testable since you can now pass the session of your choice when you call the method.
   And you are no more stuck with a session bound to a hardcoded database url.
2. I add a custom `--dburl` option to pytest using its [`pytest_addoption` hook](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html#pytest.hookspec.pytest_addoption).

   Simply add this to your top-level `conftest.py`:

   ```py
   def pytest_addoption(parser):
       parser.addoption('--dburl',
                        action='store',
                        default='<if needed, whatever your want>',
                        help='url of the database to use for tests')
   ```

   Now you can run `pytest --dburl <url of the test database>`
3. Then I can retrieve the `dburl` option from the [`request`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#request) fixture

   - From a custom fixture:

     ```py
     @pytest.fixture()
     def db_url(request):
         return request.config.getoption("--dburl")
         # ...
     ```
   - Inside a test:

     ```py
     def test_something(request):
         db_url = request.config.getoption("--dburl")
         # ...
     ```

---

At this point you are able to:

- get the test `db_url` in any test or fixture
- use it to create an engine
- create a session bound to the engine
- pass the session to a tested method

It is quite a mess to do this in every test, so you can make a usefull usage of pytest fixtures to ease the process.

Below are some fixtures I use:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def db_engine(request):
    """yields a SQLAlchemy engine which is suppressed after the test session"""
    db_url = request.config.getoption("--dburl")
    engine_ = create_engine(db_url, echo=True)

    yield engine_

    engine_.dispose()


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def db_session_factory(db_engine):
    """returns a SQLAlchemy scoped session factory"""
    return scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=db_engine))


@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def db_session(db_session_factory):
    """yields a SQLAlchemy connection which is rollbacked after the test"""
    session_ = db_session_factory()

    yield session_

    session_.rollback()
    session_.close()
```

Using the `db_session` fixture you can get a fresh and clean `db_session` for each single test.
When the test ends, the `db_session` is rollbacked, keeping the database clean.

Comment: Nice! it worked, is there a way to use the pytest's fixtures to mock a database? So tests won't need to have a real connection with the database and I can test if all methods are working fine.

Comment: @Feulo It is probably possible to use a fake database mock using pytest and the [unittest.mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#module-unittest.mock) library, but this is something I never did.

Comment: I'll take a look on the unnitest.mock documentation. Thanks!

Comment: Used this and it seems like it's is not able to handle session.commit calls during the tests as there is no nested transaction. This means tests might be commit to the database. I might be wrong as I have not fully grasped everything. But this worked for me: https://gist.github.com/kissgyorgy/e2365f25a213de44b9a2

Comment: @Tryph What if you have an intermediate Interface that inherits from Base? In order to extend some functionality of the SQLAlchemy ORM. Many thanks!

Comment: @jon I don't see why using a subclass of `Base` would prevent using this, but I never subclassed Base... In addition I cannot give a better answer with so few detail. Feel free to post a new question :)

Comment: @lorey Yes. By wrapping `session` in nested transaction, you can call `session.commit()` at anywhere of the functions you want to test , since the code sample (in the gist link) never calls `transaction.commit()` , the changes made by `session.commit()` never affects corresponding database tables, then rollback before the  outer transaction ends.

Comment: I wonder how this would look when using an async session. It's driving me nuts...