# Pytest implementing setup and tear down for every individual test: How to change setup and tear down to occur only once for the entire test suite?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy, pytest

Using Postgres, SQLAlchemy 1.4 ORM, Python 3.7, Pytest.

I have a project in `myproject/src/` and the tests for it are located in `myproject/tests/`.

I am trying to implement a cleaner way of implementing tests where the setup and tear down methods are called only once each time we run all the tests.

In **conftest.py** I have the following code which imports functions from `myproject/src/postgresdb.py`. (The tests get run from **tests.py**)

```
import asyncio
import pytest
from postgresdb import load_json, PostgresDb


ENGINE = 'postgresql+asyncpg://postgres@localhost:5432/test_db'


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def engine():
    return create_async_engine(ENGINE)


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def event_loop():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    yield loop
    loop.close()
```

When I run my tests from the command line with the `--setupshow` flag, I see that there is a setup and teardown happening for each test. I thought I could avoid this by setting up a scoped session in `conftest.py` and the setup and teardown would happen automatically only once for all the tests run. **How can I implement a cleaner setup / teardown so that they're only initialised once?**
An example of some terminal output after running tests:

```
        SETUP    F expected[0]
        tests/postgresdb_test.py::test_load_json[0] (fixtures used: expected)XFAIL (intentionally testing failure)
        TEARDOWN F expected[0]
../tests/postgresdb_test.py::test_load_json[10] 
        SETUP    F expected[33]
        tests/postgresdb_test.py::test_load_json[10] (fixtures used: expected)XFAIL (intentionally testing failure)
        TEARDOWN F expected[33]
```

I have found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58660378/how-use-pytest-to-unit-test-sqlalchemy-orm-classes) which seems to have a good description of setup / teardown, but I don't know how to integrate this with `def event_loop` required for asynchronous engines.

Comment: Have you tried `scope="module"`?

Comment: I changed to `scope=module`  in `def event_loop():` and in `def _database_url():` but this did not change anything.