# Session handling with pytest and sqlalchemy

Tags: python, unit-testing, sqlalchemy, pytest

For every unit test I want to rollback already commited statements using `pytest.fixture` and `scoped_session`.

#### Setup

- python 3.11
- sqlalchemy==2.0.3
- pytest==7.2.1
- factory-boy==3.2.1
- fastapi==0.91.0

#### Implementation

##### conftest.py

- The engine is simply created using `engine = create_engine(DATABASE_URL)`
- `init_database` creates the database if it doesn't exist using `sqlalchemy`

```py
import pytest
from sqlalchemy_utils import drop_database
from database_test_setup.manage import Session

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def db_engine():
    from settings import settings
    from database import engine, init_database, DATABASE_URL

    init_database(user=settings.DB_USER, pwd=settings.DB_PWD, host=settings.DB_HOST, port=settings.DB_PORT,
                  db_name=settings.DB_NAME)

    Session.configure(bind=engine)
    yield engine
    drop_database(DATABASE_URL)
    engine.dispose()


@pytest.fixture(scope="function", autouse=True)
def db_session(db_engine):
    session_ = Session()
    session_.begin_nested()

    yield session_

    session_.rollback()
```

##### factories.py

- `Order` is a simple SQLAlchemy model

```py
from factory import Sequence
from factory.alchemy import SQLAlchemyModelFactory

from database_test_setup.manage import Session
from order.models import Order


class BaseFactory(SQLAlchemyModelFactory):
    """Base Factory."""

    class Meta:
        """Factory configuration."""
        abstract = True
        sqlalchemy_session = Session
        sqlalchemy_session_persistence = "flush"


class OrderFactory(BaseFactory):
    id = Sequence(lambda n: n)
    quality = "X"
    start_date = "2021-09-15T17:53:00"
    end_date = "2021-09-15T15:53:00"

    class Meta:
        model = Order
```

##### manage.py

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker())
```

#### Problem

When I use the `db_session` fixture in my test to commit a statement, the statement will not be affected by `session_.rollback`.
The same is true if I set `sqlalchemy_session_persistence = "commit"` in my `SQLAlchemyModelFactory`.

I understand that this question has been [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58662370/1618893) before, but the proposed solution doesn't seem to work for me, even though I use the same setup except using a separate module for creating a `scoped_session` instead of a fixture to use additionally in my `SQLAlchemyModelFactory`.